# Android notification sounds getting suppressed by system notification

Tags: android

I have a simple app that looks for a pattern of text in the incoming text message, and then alerts. Based on the text, the alert may have to last for a minute (like a pager). 
Notification alert sound is being set off, but the problem is.. the default SMS notification alert takes over (while my alert is supposed to last for a minute or more).

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to simply provide a brief delay before you create the notification (giving the system time to do its thing first), however since you want the sound to last up to a minute or more, I would suggest not playing the sound as part of your notification. Instead, play it as an mp3 (which will be briefly interrupted by the system notification, but then returned to playing) and cancel its play early if the user does the right thing (touches your notification, opens your activity, etc.)

Comment: I already tried the first option - delaying the notification a bit. The system notification was delayed as well

Comment: If delaying caused the system to delay, its because you blocked in your receiver -- preventing the system's receiver from running. You could have had better results by starting an async thread to perform the delay and then set the notification -- without blocking your main thread (and thus blocking other receivers).

Comment: Yes, I understand that I've blocked the BroadcastMessage. And I think your idea to start an async thread would work. But, isn't this a workaround?

Isn't there a way to reserve the audio for a definite amount of time? I am wondering if AudioManager.onAudioFocusChangeListener would help?

Comment: AudioManager.onAudioFocusChangeListener did help.

Answer (score 1):

AudioManager.requestAudioFocus places a request for the audio device, which if is granted, must be handled by the AudioManager.onAudioFocusChangeListener. Do remember to call abandonAudioFocus once you are done with your stuff!